# Why does Gulp.js throw a Bus Error: 10 with gulp.watch?

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

I keep getting a `Bus error: 10` with `gulp.watch()` after a watched file changes.

Why does the `Bus error` happen with a valid gulpfile?

Here is my gulpfile:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var minifycss = require('gulp-minify-css');

gulp.task('css', function() {
  return gulp.src('css/*.css')
    .pipe(minifycss())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css/min'));
});

gulp.task('default', function() {
  gulp.watch('css/*.css', ['css']);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I also was getting this error, then realized I had a circular dependency in my sass imports.

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem from information in a similar question on Stack Overflow, [GruntJS “bus error grunt watch”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20887400/gruntjs-bus-error-grunt-watch).

There was a common issue with OS X Mavericks, and Node.js versions < v0.10.21. I was running v0.10.20.

I upgraded node, and now `gulp.watch()` is working fine.